# multiple CNN inputs with generator.flow_from_directory ??

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, convolution

I'm trying to train a two streams CNN architecture, but unfortunately, I got an unexpected result which is almost the same as one of the two streams (I have already trained every one separately). My idea is to merge two streams CNN from two different images folder (two sources) and combining them to get more accurate results.
here is my code, please tell me what I'm doing wrong :

```
## Arch
    def fusionNet(nb_classes, inputs=(3, 224, 224)):
        input_img = Input(shape=inputs, name='RGB_input')
        conv1 = Conv2D(96, (7, 7), activation="relu", name="conv1", strides=(2, 2), padding="same", 
        ## ....
        ## ....
        ## ....
        firstCNN_output = BatchNormalization(name='firstCNN_output_BN')(last_dropout)
        ##
        print(firstCNN_output._keras_shape) # I got here (None, 512, 13, 13)



        input_img2 = Input(shape=inputs, name='depth_input')
        conv12 = Conv2D(96, (7, 7), activation="relu", name="conv12", strides=(2, 2), padding="same",             kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform")(input_img2)
        #....
        #....
        #...

        SecondCNN_output = BatchNormalization(name='SecondCNN_output_BN2')(last_dropout2)
        print(SecondCNN_output._keras_shape) # I got here (None, 512, 13, 13)
    #     

        merge2CNN = merge([firstCNN_output, SecondCNN_output], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)   
        ### got here (None, 1024, 13, 13) 
        conv10 = Conv2D(
            nb_classes, (1, 1),init='glorot_uniform',
            border_mode='valid', name='conv10')(merge2CNN)
            avgpool10 = AveragePooling2D((13, 13), name='avgpool10')(conv10)

        flatten = Flatten(name='flatten')(avgpool10)
        softmax = Activation("softmax", name='softmax')(flatten)

    return Model(inputs=[input_img,input_img2], output=softmax)

## Training

sn = fusionNet(nb_classes=24)
sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, decay=0.0002, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

sn.compile( optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy')

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rescale=1./255,
zoom_range=0.01,
rotation_range=2.,
featurewise_center=True,
featurewise_std_normalization=True,)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)


def generate_generator_multiple(generator,dir1, dir2, batch_size,img_height,img_width):
    genX1 = generator.flow_from_directory(dir1,
                              target_size = (img_height,img_width),
                              class_mode = 'categorical',
                              batch_size = batch_size,
                              shuffle=False)

    genX2 = generator.flow_from_directory(dir2,
                              target_size = (img_height, img_width),
                              class_mode = 'categorical',
                              batch_size = batch_size)
    while True:
        X1i = genX1.next()
        X2i = genX2.next()
        yield [X1i[0], X2i[0]], X2i[1]  #Yield both images and their mutual label


train_generator=generate_generator_multiple(generator=train_datagen,
                               dir1=train_data_dir,
                               dir2=train_data_dir_colored,
                               batch_size=32,
                               img_height=size,
                               img_width=size)       

validation_generator=generate_generator_multiple(test_datagen,
                              dir1=validation_data_dir,
                              dir2=validation_data_dir_colored,
                              batch_size=batch_size,
                              img_height=size,
                              img_width=size)              



tensorboardcb =     keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='/workspace/sqn_224/fusion',     histogram_freq=0,         batch_size=32, write_graph=True)
sn.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples//32,
nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
validation_data=validation_generator,
validation_steps = nb_validation_samples//32, 
callbacks=[tensorboardcb])
```

Comment: What is the unexpected result? Are you getting any error message?

Comment: @sdcbr No, I didn't get any error message, but it keeps giving me the accuracy of one of the two streams. I don't know if there is something wrong! the expected results is getting better accuracy as I'm combining two sources of information..